# How do I transfer Git tags to Heroku from Travis CI?

Tags: git, heroku, travis-ci

I'm running a Python app on Heroku using Gunicorn. I want to display the output of `git describe` for versioning. It seems that none of my Git tags have been pushed to Heroku from my Travis CI deployment.

How do I either:

**A:** Push all my Git tags to Heroku from Travis, or

**B:** Fetch all tags from a remote Git repo on Heroku

---

For A, I have tried running `git push --tags --force <...>` on Travis, but Travis' `before_deploy` clause doesn't have access to Heroku credentials.

For B, I have tried running `$ git fetch --tags --prune` on Heroku, and get the following:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)
```

Comment: This explains why I get "Not a git repository": https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#compilation

`.git` is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I've seen/used in the past is to write the git details that you want to a file in your deployment during your CI or build step. Then read that file from the running app.

So in CI/build (where, presumably you have the `.git` folder and `git` command):

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD > REVISION
```

And in your app:

```
def git_revision():
    # Maybe consider memoizing this if you read it a lot
    with open("REVISION") as f:
        return f.read()
```